# Adding date to the exported sheet using variable of the date on Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

What I want to do is export a sheet to a csv file using Google Apps Script, and want to give it a specific name with the date it was exported.

Thus if successfully ran, the script would export a Google Sheet as a CSV and save it as 'Purpose Import 03-14-2023.csv' into the specific folder.

The weird thing is that the script and trigger was working fine the day before with the trigger at 5 PM and now is giving the following error code:

```
TypeError: curDate is not a function
```

However the function is defined. The code below is the function that the trigger is meant to run (with sheets and folder url renamed).

```
function exportSheetAsCSV() {
  function getFileAsBlob(exportUrl) {
    let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl, {
       muteHttpExceptions: true,
       headers: {
         Authorization: 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
       },
    });
    return response.getBlob();
  }

  
  let blob = getFileAsBlob("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/sheetURL/export?format=csv");


  var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT","MM-dd-yyyy");

  blob.setName('Daily Shipments Import ' + curDate() + '.csv');

 

  var foID = 'folderURL';
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(foID)

  
  folder.createFile(blob)

}
```

As I am writing this question out, I am thinking whether it is possible that because the Apps Script trigger had a .nearMinute() method added to it today, that this might mess with the function. The .nearMinute() method was added because we were going to set the trigger to 430PM as opposed to 5PM.

Here is the trigger function:

```
function createTrigger() {
  var triggerDay = ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY; // Change to the day you want the trigger to start on
  var triggerHour = 16; // 4 PM in 24-hour format
  var triggerMinute = 30; // Set the desired minute
  var timeZone = "America/Los_Angeles";
  
  // Create a trigger that runs the function "myFunction" every weekday at 5 PM
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("exportSheetAsCSV")
    .timeBased()
    .onWeekDay(triggerDay)
    .atHour(triggerHour)
    .nearMinute(triggerMinute)
    .inTimezone(timeZone)
    .create();
}
```

The trigger worked fine and was executed at the correct time, but failed this time, while it was not failing before.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. What does `As I am writing this out, is it possible that because the Apps Script trigger had a .nearMinute() method added to it, that this might mess with the function.` mean? And, can I ask you about the detail of the relationship between your 1st script and your 2nd script? Can you provide your current script for correctly replicating `no longer working today.`?

Comment: Welcome. "it was working yesterday and is no longer working today." You have two scripts: one create a time-driven trigger and the other to "export a sheet to a csv file". **Which of these is not working today?** What troubleshooting have you done? Have you looked at the Project Editor "Triggers" to see whether and when your triggered script was run? Have you looked at "Executions" to see whether either script was run but failed? Please read [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then provide an MRE.

Comment: @Tanaike I apologize, I could have explained better. I was trying to say that I didn't know what the issue was, but as I was posting this, it came to me to wonder whether adding the .nearMinute() method might be the issue, as that was the only change I had made before it stopped working as intended.  The function 'exportSheetAsCSV' is what I am trying to execute, and the function 'createTrigger' is when I want 'exportSheetAsCSV' to be ran. The above code is the current script.

Comment: @Tedinoz the export sheet as a csv function is not working. The troubleshooting that I have done is changing the name of the function. I have also use 'let' as opposed to 'var'. I am not very familiar with JavaScript or Google Scripts, this is actually the first one I've made. When looking at the Project Editor, the trigger worked fine, it went off at 4:30PM as intended. But it failed due to the error mentioned above. This error did not come up before.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, a little embarassing, but we only learn from mistakes, right? curDate is a variable, not a function. The following is what I was running in the exportsSheetAsCSV function:

```
blob.setName('Daily Shipments Import ' + curDate() + '.csv');
```

And what it should be is this:

```
blob.setName('Daily Shipments Import ' + curDate + '.csv');
```

Thank you for the help y'all.